# In RDLC report's IIF condition's else block always executed and throwing the exception

Tags: c#, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to execute the below expression in RDLC report against the column **MyColumn**,

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Incident_Custom_Column_152.Value)=True,
    "Nothing",
    Fields!Incident_Custom_Column_152.value.IndexOf("/")
)
```

And I am getting the #Error when Incident_Custom_Column_152.value is null. Please let us know why else block evaluated?

Comment: See https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-use-the-isnothing-inspection-function-in-ssrs

Comment: The example will work only for value, it will throw exception if we have any string operation like Fields!Incident_Custom_Column_152.IndexOf, Fields!Incident_Custom_Column_152.Splite etc.. As per my knowledge both expression is executed first, Please let us know how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding the custom function and then called custom function from column expression,

### function

Public Function TestFucntion(ByVal rca as String) as String
Dim result as String
If IsNothing(rca) Then
result=rca
Else
If(rca.IndexOf("/") = -1) Then
result=rca.Substring(0, Len(rca) - rca.IndexOf("/") - 1 )
Else
result=rca
End If
End If
Return result
End Function

called like below in column expression

=Code.TestFucntion(Fields!Incident_Custom_Column_153.Value)

Comment: All code is doing is casting rca to a string before testing that it is "Nothing".